# I want to create a service that allows my company's products to move pages only for the products that customers have

Tags: integration, product

This article was written using a translator.

There are many products in my company.
Like Atlasian, I want to create a service that allows my company's products to move pages only for the products that customers have.
In order to do so, you need to know the products of each customer, and I need to make sure that only those products can be clicked, but can you not use the database?
Using the database makes it so complicated that I want to implement it as simple as possible.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You need to know a programming language/ framework that allows you to create a service/api.

There are various ones available.

Search on the internet.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Of course, I do programming.
I will code using Java and spring framework.
The thing is, I'm curious about the algorithm(or architecture) how to implement it.

For example, when a product is installed, information that the customer has installed the product is stored in a database, and based on that, only the product that the customer has is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

The architecture of a service is slightly different from directly having a data entry form that stores into a database.

Most apis'/ service entails you creating classes to do CRUD operations(i.e create,read,update and delete operations) by coding classes and then consuming the API into the application.

So yes you can have within the API classes that can be called and then used to store information that the customer has installed into a database, and also retrieve product values specific to a specific customer.

See API as mid layer between front end,and database